# Firestore query interval in interval

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

in our scenario the events have a begin and end time stamp, the event may span over 2 days or 3 months

```
event = {
    start: 1652180300308
    end: 1653217107596
}
```

and we want to get a list of all events starting or in progress for this month.
Is it possible to make such a query without creating additional fields ?

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your current data structure you will need to perform a range filter on both `start` and `end` to determine whether the event falls into a certain month. As shown in the documentation on Firestore's [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations), that is not possible:

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

To allow the query, one solution would be to add an array field with all the months that the event is active in, so that you can then use an `array-contains` filter on that.

Comment: how many months is tooooo many ???

Comment: There's no objective way to answer that. If you feel you have more items than you're comfortable, consider if there's another way to model the data that fits your needs and feelings better. For example, consider if you can change the granularity (i.e. years instead of months) or the scope (e.g. only the months for a specific year).